# Am I allowed to take alcoholic beverages from the US in my luggage, if I'm under 21?

Tags: usa, alcohol, american-airlines, dutch-citizens

I am a 19 year old Dutch person living in the Netherlands and with family in the United States. I have been in the USA often and found that they sell a few special alcoholic beverages that I enjoy which aren't for sale in the Netherlands and that I would like to take with me back home.

In the Netherlands the minimum age to drink alcohol is 18, rather than 21 in the United States. Now I am 19 and wonder whether I am allowed to take some of these drinks in my baggage back home.

- Am I allowed to carry alcohol with me (without drinking it, leaving the bottle unopened) at age 19?
- Would this be allowed in my suitcase that goes into the hold?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49909/discussion-on-question-by-markinson-am-i-allowed-to-take-alcoholic-beverages-fro).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In general, it is illegal for an individual under 21 years of age to possess alcohol, whether open or sealed, in a public place in the United States. You would have to consult the laws of the state you are in, as well as any states you transit through, to see if this is the case for you specifically.

A related matter is whether or not it is legal for an individual under 21 years of age to export alcohol for personal use. Although CBP state that it is illegal for individuals under 21 to *import* alcohol, it makes no comment on the export of alcohol. One might therefore infer that there is no federal issue with exporting.

There is no problem with putting alcohol in checked luggage.

As a practical matter, if the alcohol is contained in your luggage the whole time, it is extremely unlikely that you will face any trouble, especially if you are accompanied by an adult when travelling to the airport through check-in; it is not, for example, the case that your luggage would be tagged with your age, and as the vast majority of travellers are over 21 years old, TSA (who are not law enforcement anyway) are not on the lookout for alcohol in luggage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As additional information, my family walks with me throught the airport till the point where we have to say bye, so I'm always accompanied with an adult. Now, technically, if I would put it in my suitcase and let my family carry the bag for me, I'm not in posession of the alcohol but my family is (right? it's just in my suitcase but I don't walk around with it). And when I check in my luggage, it isn't in my posession anymore either. Sounds fair enough to me!

Comment: If you check in as a group, all bags are typically tagged as the first passenger's property, so it would not even be "your" suitcase anymore.

Comment: Don't get too carried away with glee ... anything in your luggage is considered your possessions and once you check that bag, you have legally claimed that it is your possessions. If TSA finds drugs in your bag, you get busted.  If they find illegal alcohol, you get busted.  Just because mommy carried it in for you, doesn't absolve you of responsibility for it. While TSA is not specifically chartered to enforce local drinking age, they have amazing latitude and can call upon a airport police officer to enforce underage possession charges if desired.

Comment: Agree with @Tom, although I think the chances of getting busted are quite low. Consider that you are allowed to bring 1L of liquor into the EU without additional fees. But also regarding this, chances of getting busted are quite low - as a young normal traveller coming from unsuspicious countries chances to get controlled are pretty low.

Comment: @Tom I'll let your mum carry it for me then instead! No but I get it, thanks for the info ;p

Comment: *"not on the lookout for alcohol in luggage"* - the problem is, WaiWai, they are on the lookout for *trouble*. Extreme example: you're wearing a silly tshirt that has a joke about "terrorists!" That is 100.00000% legal. But you'd instantly be flagged for hours-long searches, interviews etc. Further, the issue at hand *is indeed technically illegal* as you say in sentence one.  While (as you say) they are not authorities looking for that particular illegality as such, *any illegal activity* is a red flag to them.

Comment: I just think you can't be too careful, @Markinson.  I mean you're going to the USA, far and away the most statist, papers-please large country.  You're talking like a dude from Holland or something who thinks you can just go through life without being troubled by The Man.  Wait - you are from Holland!  :)

Comment: @JoeBlow haha I like your attitude :-) but yes that's why I primarily asked this question, to clarify what the risks are. I rather don't take the risk of getting in trouble, even though that chance might be just a small percentage.

Comment: If you think about it, you're going to a country where >> adults are not allowed to drink beer << and you're asking "So should I sneak some booze in my luggage?"  Heh!

Comment: @JoeBlow true that hahaha didn't look at it like that yet!

Comment: @JoeBlow I think Russia and China have words to say about large statist papers-please countries.

Answer (score 15):

Alcohol is not a federal issue, it's a state issue. So, the TSA is legally completely unconcerned with the presence of a bottle of booze in your luggage. When the TSA searches your luggage, they are concerned with security, not state alcohol regulations. They *will not know how old you are*. Yea, that's in your traveller data, but they are not going to look at that data unless they find something disturbing, and a bottle of booze is not disturbing.

Comment: This one should be the correct answer. It really should not be an issue.

Comment: Alcohol is actually regulated by multiple federal departments, from the ATF to the FDA to the TTB, including production, sale, and especially export (exporting particularly being a federal issue). It's unclear if taking something with you on an international flight is strictly "export" as that usually refers to wholesale, but it's both a state and federal concern: https://www.ttb.gov/itd/exporting_alcohol.shtml I don't know if the TSA actually will care about alcohol, but they are free to refer it to local police like drugs: https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=marijuana

Comment: Individual possession of small quantities is not anything that the ATF, FDA, or TTB pay attention to, and there is absolutely no export control on single bottles. Sure, the TSA could call the police, and elephants could fall from the sky.

Answer (score 3):

I know you already accepted an answer but the easiest option would be to have your family mail the alcohol to yourself in the Netherlands.  This way here you are never in possession of the alcohol while in the States and can claim the package when you are legal to posses the alcohol.

Comment: Just check postage before you commit as the cheaper options exclude alcohol and the others are very expensive. It might be cheaper to ask your best alcohol shop at home if they do imports from the USA or know others who do. (Relative wanted a $10 bottle of wisky and it would cost $100 to get it send. Just $5 extra when imported through a friendly booze shop.)

Comment: Note that, at least related to the USPS, you are prohibited from mailing alcohol internationally. https://www.usps.com/ship/shipping-restrictions.htm and same with DHL: http://www.dhl-usa.com/en/express/shipping/shipping_advice/alcoholic_beverages/exporting_alcohol.html Not that people might get away with it - but it should be clear that it is prohibited, and may be illegal (state and federally).